# Compiling SWC file with ant fails: "include-sources doesn't support the path-element attribute"

Tags: ant, build, swc, compc

I am trying to compile a src folder into a SWC file. 
But it returns the following error:

```
build.xml:9: include-sources doesn't support the "path-element" attribute
```

This is my build file:

```
<project name="My SWC build" basedir="." default="compile">
<property file="build.properties"/>
<taskdef resource="flexTasks.tasks" classpath="${FLEX_HOME}/ant/lib/flexTasks.jar"/>
<target name="init">
    <delete dir="${DEPLOY_DIR}"/>
    <mkdir dir="${DEPLOY_DIR}"/>
</target>
<target name="compile" depends="init">
    <compc output="${DEPLOY_DIR}/${SWC_NAME}.swc">
        <include-sources path-element="${SRC_DIR}"/>
    </compc>
</target>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Use :
<include-source dir="${SRC_DIR}"/> –or– <is dir="${SRC_DIR}"/>

instead of:
 <include-sources path-element="${SRC_DIR}"/>
```